# sql query from 4 tables

Tags: sql

I'm beginner and I need help!!!!!

I have a database:

- **article:** `id, name, description, id_pic, lang, date`
- **category:** `id_cat, name_cat`
- **pictures:** `id_pic, image`
- **sub_cat:** `id_subcat, name_subcat, id_cat`

I need to SELECT `name, desc, image, name_subcat` this on

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.name, a.desc, sc.name_subcat, p.picture, a.id_subcat 
FROM 
    article a, subcategory sc 
LEFT JOIN 
    pictures p ON a.id_pic = p.id_pic 
WHERE 
    a.id_subcat = sc.id_subcat 
    AND a.id_subcat IN (SELECT sc.id_subcat 
                        FROM subcategory sc 
                        WHERE id_cat = (SELECT id_cat  
                                        FROM category 
                                        WHERE name_cat = '???????'))
```

Comment: What are you using mssql 2008, mssql 2005, mssql 2000 or mysql etc?

Comment: What are you looking for? What criteria??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.desc, 
       sc.name_subcat, p.picture, a.id_subcat 
FROM article a, 
LEFT JOIN subcategory sc ON a.id_subcat = sc.id_subcat 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON sc.id_cat = c.id_cat
LEFT JOIN pictures p     ON a.id_pic    = p.id_pic 
WHERE c.name_cat = '??????'
```

Just join the table `subcategory` with other tables instead of `where a.id_subcat = sc.id_subcat`. This join will ensure that any `a.id_subcat` is in `subcategory`, so you can get rid of the subquery in the where clause too. You will also need to join the `categories c` table too.

You will need to choose the `JOIN` type whether `left` ot `INNER`, depending on what data to select from your table.

Comment: I am not sure which join type is needed for their query :) But it is worth mentioning that using `c.name_cat` in the WHERE clause will negate the outer join on `categories c`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some joins defines.

Four tables:

**Article**:

- ID
- Name
- Description
- ID_Pic
- Lang
- Date

**Category**:

- id_cat
- name_cat

**Subcategory**:

- id_subcat
- name_subcat
- id_cat

**Pictures**:

- id_pic
- image,

We need to see how Category/Subcategory relate to articles. Do articles have a category they are linked to that you are missing afield from?

When you can get me these answers i can go through a join process for you.

EDIT: I see the missing field. Please ignore, good answer above me.

Regards,
Jason

Comment: article have one more field: id_subcat